# How can I cancel a Runnable.postDelayed() timer and reset it on button click?

Tags: java, android

I've made a quick quiz app where users have 5 seconds to answer a question, I have a postDelayed() set up that it launches out of the quiz activity via an intent, however I can't get the postDelayed() to cancel itself when the correct answer is clicked.

Any ideas how I can achieve this? (5 second timer cancelled and reset on button click)

Edit: Situation is different to the possible duplicate in that I'm not looking to reset the timer once it's completed, but to stop it mid run. Eg. Timer runs for 5 seconds, after 3 seconds users clicks button, which should reset timer to 5, however currently the new timer starts but the old timer continues and 2 seconds later the postDelayed() action executes

Comment: Search better through SO. Your answer or at least the same logic is here:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221829/restart-countdown-timer-with-new-time-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restart Countdown Timer with new time android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221829/restart-countdown-timer-with-new-time-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.removeCallbacks()` method on a `Handler` object to remove pending posts.

You may be interested in using RxJava and the `.timeout()` operator instead.

```
mObservable
    .timeout(5, SECONDS)
    .subscribe()
```